# Data sovereignty for Teams bot framework channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a customer wanting to use Bot Framework that has very strict data sovereignty requirements - anything to / from the user must stay in Australia. The bot endpoint is inside their Azure environment (Australia East) in an ASE. They want to use Teams as the channel. Their Teams / Office 365 sub is in Australia. They are concerned that the bot registration itself is in the Global region, whereas the other bits they control are in Australia.

Can we confirm that all elements of communications would stay within Aus? I'm not quite clear on the fine details of how messages from a Teams chat are routed through the bot connector service on their way to the endpoint in Azure. I've seen various diagrams such as this one, but nothing that goes into the level of detail we need - https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app/wiki/Solution-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed for us that if the Teams instance is in Australia, and that if the Azure tenant is hosted in Australia, then user traffic to/from the bot will remain within Australia.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stick to APAC serviceUrl. (/apac)

Comment: Thanks Leo, could you elaborate on that at all? Is this the URL the bot uses when replying? I don't remember being able to configure that?

Comment: @Leeroy yes, you need the service Url when you communicate with Bot Framework.